# Rearrage sequence so that adjacent numbers add to perfect squares

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, sorting

Consider the array:

```
original_array1[17] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}
```

I want to sort it in such a way that:

1. Sum of adjacent numbers should be a perfect square
2. You cannot reuse a number

So a possible solution is:

```
16 9 7 2 14 11 5 4 12 13 3 6 10 15 1 8 17
```

I write a C++ program to get this done using a recursive function and it works.

I was wondering how can I improve the program to:

1. Make it more readable and easy to understand (variable names, better handling or elimination of boundary conditions, comments etc.)
2. Use better library functions or C++ language features to make the code compact.
3. Is there a better algorithm/strategy that I can use instead of using recursive functions.

The motivation for this came from a daily problem posted on brilliant.org, I thought I would solve it by writing a program. But now I want to ask the community for pointers on how to become better at coding in general.

Here is the code have:

```
//Compile using g++ -std=c++11 arrange.cpp 

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int original_array1[17] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};

bool isSumPerfectSquare(int x, int y) {  
    long double sr = sqrt((long double)x + (long double)y);
    return ((sr - floor(sr)) == 0);
}

int * ArrangeNumbers(int * done, int * remaining, int size_done, int size_remaining) {
    static int ctr = 0;
    // cout<<"ArrangeNumbers() "<< (ctr++) << endl<<"    ";
    // if(done != nullptr) {
    //  for(int jj = 0; jj<size_done;jj++) {
    //      cout<<done[jj]<<" ";
    //  }
    // }
    // cout<<" | ";
    // if(remaining != nullptr) {
    //  for(int jj = 0; jj<size_remaining;jj++) {
    //      cout<<remaining[jj]<<" ";
    //  }
    // }
    // cout<<endl;
    if(size_remaining == 1) { // Border Case 1: Last number remaining, lets check if pairs up with the last number in sorted array
        if(isSumPerfectSquare(done[size_done-1],remaining[0])) {
            int * finally_done = (int *) calloc(size_done+1,sizeof(int));
            for(int jj = 0; jj<size_done;jj++) {
                finally_done[jj] = done[jj];
            }
            finally_done[size_done] = remaining[0];
            return finally_done;
        } else {
            return nullptr;
        }
    } else if(size_done == 0) { // Border Case 2:  Come back and choose the first number again
        int * done1 = (int *) calloc(size_done+1,sizeof(int));
        int * remaining1 = (int *) calloc(size_remaining-1,sizeof(int));

        for(int kk = 0; kk<size_remaining;kk++) {
            done1[0] = remaining[kk];
            for(int ll = 0; ll<kk;ll++) {
                remaining1[ll] = remaining[ll];
            }
            for(int ll = kk+1; ll<size_remaining;ll++) {
                remaining1[ll-1] = remaining[ll];
            }
            int * sr_arr = ArrangeNumbers(done1, remaining1, size_done+1, size_remaining-1);
            if(sr_arr != nullptr) {
                free(done1);
                free(remaining1);
                return sr_arr;
            }
        }
        free(done1);
        free(remaining1);
        return nullptr;
    } else {
        int * done1 = (int *) calloc(size_done+1,sizeof(int));
        int * remaining1 = (int *) calloc(size_remaining-1,sizeof(int));

        // Copy array till now
        if(done != nullptr) {
            for(int jj = 0; jj<size_done;jj++) {
                done1[jj] = done[jj];
            }
        }

        // Choose next number and respawn
        for(int kk = 0; kk<size_remaining;kk++) {
            if(isSumPerfectSquare(done1[size_done-1],remaining[kk])) {
                done1[size_done] = remaining[kk];
                for(int ll = 0; ll<kk;ll++) {
                    remaining1[ll] = remaining[ll];
                }
                for(int ll = kk+1; ll<size_remaining;ll++) {
                    remaining1[ll-1] = remaining[ll];
                }
                int * sr_arr = ArrangeNumbers(done1, remaining1, size_done+1, size_remaining-1);
                if(sr_arr != nullptr) {
                    free(done1);
                    free(remaining1);
                    return sr_arr;
                }
            }
        }
        free(done1);
        free(remaining1);
        return nullptr;
    }
}

int main() {
    int * sorted_array = ArrangeNumbers(nullptr, original_array1, 0, 17);
    cout<<"Original Array :";
    for(int i = 0; i<17;i++) {
        cout<<" "<<original_array1[i];
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Sorted Array   :";
    if(sorted_array != nullptr) {
        for(int i = 0; i<17;i++) {
            cout<<" "<<sorted_array[i];
        }
        free(sorted_array);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Compilation options

Use more warnings, e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra`.  This will identify the unused variable `ctr`, for instance.

## Avoid `using namespace std`

Bringing all names in from a namespace is problematic; `namespace std` particularly so. See [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).

## Choice of type

If all the numbers are guaranteed to be positive, consider using an unsigned type for the array elements.

Prefer using `std::array` over raw (C-style) arrays.

## Checking for perfect square

It's good that we have a self-contained function for checking whether a number is a perfect square.  However, it has accuracy problems when values reach the limit of a `double`'s mantissa.  It's also relatively slow, due to the use of `std::sqrt()`.  One thing we could do instead is to create a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set`) of the possible square numbers, and then simply test for membership of that set.

That looks something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

unsigned original_array1[17] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};

bool isSumPerfectSquare(unsigned x) {
    static auto const squares =
        []{
            std::unordered_set<unsigned> s;
            auto max = *std::max_element(std::begin(original_array1), std::end(original_array1));
            for (auto value = 1u, diff = 1u;  value < max * 2;  value += (diff += 2))
                s.insert(value);
            return s;
        }();

    return squares.find(x) != squares.end();
}
```

## Prefer `new[]` and `delete[]`

When writing C++, prefer the `new` and `delete` operators and their array counterparts rather than C-style `std::malloc()`, `std::calloc()`, `std::realloc()` and `std::free()`.  Prefer smart pointers and collections to bare pointers.

However, this algorithm shouldn't need any allocations at all, if we modify the input in place.

Here's how I'd do that, using `std::swap` to move each candidate in turn to the front of the array:

```
// shuffle [a..b), given preceding number
bool arrange_numbers(unsigned prev, unsigned *a, unsigned *b)
{
    if (a == b) {
        // no more numbers; we've done it!
        return true;
    }

    for (unsigned *p = a;  p != b;  ++p) {
        if (is_perfect_square(prev + *p)) {
            std::swap(*a, *p);
            if (arrange_numbers(*a, a+1, b)) {
                // found a match
                return true;
            }
            // reinstate the order, for our caller
            std::swap(*a, *p);
        }
    }

    // no satisfactory solution
    return false;
}


bool arrange_numbers(std::array<unsigned,17>& array)
{
    unsigned *a = array.begin();
    unsigned *b = array.end();

    for (unsigned *p = a;  p != b;  ++p) {
        std::swap(*a, *p);
        if (arrange_numbers(*a, a+1, b)) {
            // found a match
            return true;
        }
    }

    // no matches
    return false;
}
```

---

## Full modified code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>


std::array<unsigned,17> numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};

bool is_perfect_square(unsigned x) {
    static auto const squares =
        []{
            std::unordered_set<unsigned> s;
            auto max = *std::max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
            for (auto value = 1u, diff = 1u;  value < max * 2;  value += (diff += 2))
                s.insert(value);
            return s;
        }();

    return squares.find(x) != squares.end();
}


// shuffle [a..b), given preceding number
bool arrange_numbers(unsigned prev, unsigned *a, unsigned *b)
{
    if (a == b) {
        // no more numbers; we've done it!
        return true;
    }

    for (unsigned *p = a;  p != b;  ++p) {
        if (is_perfect_square(prev + *p)) {
            std::swap(*a, *p);
            if (arrange_numbers(*a, a+1, b)) {
                // found a match
                return true;
            }
            // reinstate the order, for our caller
            std::swap(*a, *p);
        }
    }

    // no satisfactory solution
    return false;
}


bool arrange_numbers(std::array<unsigned,17>& array)
{
    unsigned *a = array.begin();
    unsigned *b = array.end();

    for (unsigned *p = a;  p != b;  ++p) {
        std::swap(*a, *p);
        if (arrange_numbers(*a, a+1, b)) {
            // found a match
            return true;
        }
    }

    // no matches
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Original array:";
    for (auto i: numbers) {
            std::cout << " " << i;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    if (arrange_numbers(numbers)) {
        std::cout << "Sorted array:";
        for (auto i: numbers) {
            std::cout << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Better strategy** at the first glance does not exist. Consider a graph formed by the numbers an array, with the edges connecting vertices which add up to a perfect square. The problem then is reduced to finding a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem). The problem is known to be NP-complete. There is an algorithm solving it in \$O(n^2 2^n)\$ time; in general case it is better than brute force, but still exponential.

Your case *could* have a better asymptotic, because the graph has a very particular structure. For starters, for path to exist the should be no more than 2 vertices of the degree 1 (if the array had 18, there would be 3 such vertices). Also your graph is very sparsely connected, and has quite a few vertices of degree 2. This suggests a heuristic similar to the [Warnsdorf's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorf's_rule): start with a vertex of the least degree, and always inspect the neighbors in the ascending order of degrees (smallest first).

For example in your array, starting with `16` (degree 1) forces the resulting sequence with not a single branch point.

Comment: Even if you can reduce a problem to an NPC problem, it does not mean the original problem is necessarily hard.